# Unknown Undefined in Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm still learning about OOP in javascript. While browsing some tutorials I've encountered this code

```js
function Employee () {}

Employee.prototype.firstName = "Abhijit";
Employee.prototype.lastName = "Patel";
Employee.prototype.startDate = new Date();
Employee.prototype.signedNDA = true;
Employee.prototype.fullName = function () {
 console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName); 
};

var abhijit = new Employee () //
console.log(abhijit.fullName()); // Abhijit Patel & undefined
console.log(abhijit.signedNDA);// true
```

What I would like to ask is why does `abhijit.fullName()` displays undefined?

I'm not asking how to resolve this, I just wanna know why? Thank you.

Comment: Because `fullName()` doesn't return anything. `console.log(abhijit.fullName())` is the equivalent of `console.log(undefined)`

Comment: `abhijit.fullName()` is **not** displaying `undefined`. You are logging the return value of `abhijit.fullName()` in `console.log(abhijit.fullName())`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: @Phil but why does it return `Abhijit Patel` and after `undefined`

Comment: It doesn't **return** anything. There is no `return` statement. The function itself *logs* `this.firstName + " " + this.lastName` because it itself calls `console.log`, and then returns `undefined` (the default return value). The "outer" `console.log` logs that return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of `console.log(abhijit.fullName())` breaks up into the following:

1) execution of `console.log(abhijit.firstName + " " + abhijit.lastName)`, which comes from inner `abhijit.fullName()` call, which prints a string and which returns nothing (say `undefined`);

2) execution of outer `console.log(undefined)` where `undefined` is the result of (1).

---

To avoid such a behaviour you need to change your code a bit:

```
Employee.prototype.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
console.log(abhijit.fullName());
```

or

```
Employee.prototype.printFullName = function () {
  console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
};
abhijit.printFullName();
```

---

Also, I would recommend not to keep specific data on prototype, but on instance:

```
function Employee(first, last) {
 this.firstName = first;
 this.lastName = last;
}

Employee.prototype.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};

var abhijit = new Employee('Abhijit', 'Patel');
console.log(abhijit.fullName());
```

Comment: Not exactly. While it's true that `console.log` does not return anything, OP's code does not return the value from `console.log`

Comment: Actually it's equal to `console.log(abhijit.firstName + " " + abhijit.lastName); console.log((function(){})())`

Comment: I actually know that using `return` would solve the problem.. I was just confused why it also displays undefined...

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer to be more accurate

Comment: @dhilt could you explain clearly *execution of `console.log(undefined)` where undefined is the result of (1)*. I don't really understand this..Sorry.

Comment: @ShadowFiend The result of (1) is the result of `abhijit.fullName()` call due to the order of execution in `console.log(abhijit.fullName())`. And this result (undefined) becomes an argument of outer `console.log` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, as already noted, is that your fullName() method does not return anything, hence the undefined result.

Not that you asked, but your example is also confusing instance and class type data. Consider changing to the following:

```
function Employee(first, last, signedNDA) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
   this.startDate = new Date();
   this.signedNDA = signedNDA;
}
```